# How can I encode characters like emojis as UTF8 without unpaired surrogate characters?

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, emoji

I have strings with a variety of characters that need to be written to Google BigQuery, which requires strict UTF8 strings. When trying to write strings with a wide variety of emoji input, I get an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unpaired surrogate at index 3373
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Utf8.encodedLengthGeneral(Utf8.java:93)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Utf8.encodedLength(Utf8.java:67)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.StringUtf8Coder.getEncodedElementByteSize(StringUtf8Coder.java:145)
...
```

I have a workaround for this problem, to simply strip all surrogate characters from Strings:

```
    private static String removeSurrogates(String query) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < query.length(); i++) {
            char c = query.charAt(i);
            if (!(Character.isHighSurrogate(c) || Character.isLowSurrogate(c))) {
                sb.append(c);
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

However, this results in a string like

⚔⌨⛳⛏

Being reduced to just four emojis

⚔⌨⛳⛏

Is there a proper way to convert these characters into UTF8 without loss,  and without using unpaired surrogates?

(Apologies, my understanding of character sets in general is not great)

Comment: Encode as UTF8?

Comment: The input data is from a file that is already UTF8 encoded. We test that it is using com.google.protobuf.ByteString.isValidUtf8(), and then using the String from loggedBytes.toStringUtf8(), but when we attempt to write the String, we get the unpaired surrogate exceptions.

Comment: The file will be converted to UTF-16 (a Java `char`) when you read the file into a `String`.  That's why you have surrogate pairs.  If you just convert it back, the surrogate pairs disappear.

Comment: Thanks, do you have an example of how to just convert it back?

Comment: Not with protobuf.  Do you have a [mcve] to post so we can see what you are really doing?

Comment: I found the problem. We are using org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4 to convert HTML entities in strings to their non-encoded forms. This seems to mangle some non-latin characters. For example, passing the string "Italien " through this method converts it into "Italien ?" (the last character gets mangled). So, not a dataflow or bigquery problem it turns out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. We are using org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4 to convert HTML entities in strings to their non-encoded forms. This seems to mangle some non-latin characters. For example, passing the string "Italien " through this method converts it into "Italien ?" (the last character gets mangled)

Passing "⚔⌨⛳⛏" through this method converts it to "????????⚔⌨?⛳???"

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;

public class CharacterTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String good = "⚔⌨⛳⛏";
        String bad = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(good);
        System.out.println(good + "->" + bad);
    }
}

⚔⌨⛳⛏->????????⚔⌨?⛳???
```

Now to find an alternative HTML entity decoder...

Answer (score 0):

`Is there a proper way to convert these characters into UTF8`  Probably, if you just send the string it'll be converted to UTF-8.  That's how Java's encoders work.

If it doesn't and you are sending binary, you can just convert directly:

```
private static byte[] removeSurrogates(String query) {
    return query.getBytes( "UTF-8" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me get out of Java for a second to show that BigQuery can deal with emojis:

```
CREATE TABLE `public_dump.emoji_test`
AS
SELECT "⚔⌨⛳⛏" emojis
```

Then to test for presence:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `fh-bigquery.public_dump.emoji_test`
WHERE emojis LIKE '%%'

1
```

Doing this with Python is straightforward:

[image]

Inserting new data isn't a problem either:

[image]

I'm sorry I don't know how to fix this with Java, but I hope that it helps to see this proof of BigQuery's API abilities to handle emojis with grace.

Comment: Thank you for the response. There must be a problem in our Dataflow job that is not setting the coder correctly or something before writing to BigQuery. I am struggling to come up with a minimal verifiable example because the flow from raw log file through to BigQuery is quite lengthy and complicated.

Comment: If this is Dataflow, try with that tag too

Comment: I found the problem. We are using org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4 to convert HTML entities in strings to their non-encoded forms. This seems to mangle some non-latin characters. For example, passing the string "Italien " through this method converts it into "Italien ?" (the last character gets mangled). So, not a dataflow or bigquery problem it turns out