# Big Query - extract json field which contains emoji?

Tags: google-bigquery

In my BQ database table I have a column called `payload` which contains raw facebook webhooks JSON payloads as string. One of them contains a text with an emoji like `Sample` . In big query it look like

```
{"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"xxxx","time":1602757469275,"messaging":[{"sender":{"id":"xxxx"},"recipient":{"id":"xxxx"},"timestamp":1602757469062,"message":{"mid":"m_xxxx","text":"Sample \ud83c\udfe6","quick_reply":{"payload":"{\"key\": \"value\"}"},"tags":{"source":"source"}}}]}]}
```

I would like to create a view with a column `text` with extracted `text` field value from the raw json. I created an sql like

```
SELECT
JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(payload, '$.entry[0].messaging[0].message.text') as text,
FROM `my_table.facebook.webhook_received`
```

Sadly the result I get looks like that `Sample ��`

Does anyone know how to make big query decode the emoji properly or at least just not change it to those � signs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those characters you have embedded are not for a bank icon which is your issue I believe.
Run the following in BQ and it returns the desired emoji:
`select " Sample \U0001f3e6"`

Ref:https://emojipedia.org/bank/

The two you have provided seem to default to the '?', invalid character
http://unicode.scarfboy.com/?s=U%2Bdfe6

edit: what ever is handling the message maybe throwing the encodings you're seeing in your message which may be the actual problem.

Comment: I cannot agree because when I run my js code like ```console.log("Sample \ud83c\udfe6")``` the output is correct and contains the emoji

Comment: I validated the console output you sent and see what you mean.  Looks to me like BQ is parsing each component individually resulting in the double ?.

Comment: So looking into it a little more seems like BQ handles emojis in the Python encoding (what i provided in my answer).  The string you provided is Java encoding, see variations here:
https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f3e6/index.htm

Here is another question that is similar if it helps:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55699140/how-can-i-encode-characters-like-emojis-as-utf8-without-unpaired-surrogate-chara

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar issue and fixed it using `PARSE_JSON`.
In my personal case:

`JSON_VALUE(payload, "$.key")` returned a `�`

while:

`JSON_VALUE(PARSE_JSON(payload), "$.key")` returned the right emoji.

Hope this can help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using BigQuery Python client and its `load_table_from_json` method, there is a Unicode bug (especially its byte is over 0xFFFF, like ) in the previous version, and I have submitted this bug fix which is already included in the latest release include it, https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery/releases/tag/v2.24.0. By the way, you should use `\U0001F3E6`, not `\ud83c\udfe6` (UTF-16 hex type) to present  in your Python code with BigQuery.

Unicode Character 'BANK': https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f3e6/index.htm,
https://charbase.com/1f3e6-unicode-bank

Comment: Thanks for pointing this. I have modified the answers to the other similar questions and just left the URL of the answer to this question.